# Adding provider's services sets it to null

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I'm clearly not understanding something with dependency injection in Angular.  I've got a service which uses other services.  I would like to have both provided  in the same component.  My component looks like this:

```
@Component(
    /// ...
    providers: const [
      MediatorService,
    ])
class ReviewTableComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  final MediatorService _mediatorService;

  ReviewTableComponent(
    this._mediatorService,
  );

  /// ...
}
```

Where `MediatorService` is a service that uses another service called `QuoteCompositionService`.  Like this, the component renders fine, and I can call methods on the `MediatorService`.  Obviously, anything which uses the `QuoteCompositionService` fails, because it's not provided elsewhere.

So, if I add the `QuoteCompositionService` to the same component, like this

```
@Component(
    /// ...
    providers: const [
      QuoteCompositionService,
      MediatorService,
    ])
class ReviewTableComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  final QuoteCompositionService _quoteCompositionService;
  final MediatorService _mediatorService;

  ReviewTableComponent(
    this._quoteCompositionService,
    this._mediatorService,
  );

  /// ...
}
```

then I would expect to be able to call all of the methods on `MediatorService`.
However, I now get an error saying that `_mediatorService` is `null`.  Why would adding `QuoteCompositionService` to the providers list make `_mediatorService` `null`?

I assume I have to have `QuoteCompositionService` provided prior to my `ReviewTableComponent` being instantiated.  However, I don't understand why `_mediatorService` would be `null` where it wasn't previously.

Here is some of the `MediatorService`, if it helps. (Maybe I should be doing something else here?)

```
@Injectable()
class MediatorService {
  final QuoteCompositionService _quoteCompositionService;

  /// ...

  MediatorService(
    this._quoteCompositionService,
    /// ...
  );
  /// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  There was a typo in the `QuoteCompositionService` providers list.  Apparently typos there don't result in the compilation failing.